# Status bar mixes in with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have UITableviewController which contains a searchbar at the top and table rows underneath. I've set the navbar to hidden and position the view 20 px from top to account for status bar.

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if(!app.statusBarHidden) {
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,app.statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - app.statusBarFrame.size.height)];
        }}
```

This works. When the view first loads, the status bar and the view appear fine.

[image: view after first load]

However, if I tap on one of the tablerows, that transitions to a new pushed view. Upon coming back from the new view to the view which contains the tableview, the statusbar intermingles with the tableviewcontroller view.

[image: view after second load]

The viewdidappear is called but it has no effect. Is there a better way of doing this? In one of my other views, I manually added 20 px in the storyboard. However, with this tableviewcontroller, I couldn't figure out a way of doing that. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7){
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of tableViewController take a UIViewController, inside which take a searchBar on top and a tableView below it this may solve Your Problem

Comment: You're right. That would fix the issue. Its just that my tableviewcontroller contains a lot of code. It would take a couple of days to re-write and test it as a UIViewController.